# How many missions did the SG-1 team go on through the stargate?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the TV show *Stargate SG-1*, how many missions through the stargate did the SG-1 team go on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depends. Is there conclusive evidence we were shown all missions? Perhaps they went on a lot of boring ones, which never were shown in an episode. Also what counts as mission? If they go on a mission to do x on planet y and they return saying, "x wasn't on y but we learned it's on planet z". Would going to z count as a new mission or as the same mission again?

Anyway, at some point they celebrate the 200th episode, coinciding  In-Universe with Mitchell's 200th *trip* through the gate. He was introduced in episode 175 (Avalon). Which means 25 episodes mean roughly 200 trips. If we extrapolate from that, we get about 214*200/25 = 1712 trips in total. Seeing that they return to earth via the gate in most cases, gives an upper bound of about 850 missions.

I'd say at least every second episode they get a completely new mission (almost all missions involve the gate), so that would leave us with a lower bound of about 100.

I guess, if you want a more precise answer than between one and eight hundred, somebody will have to do the counting, re-watching every single episode.

Comment: We weren't shown all the missions, they repeatedly mention places and events we aren't shown. At one point, Carter actually flings out a number of worlds they've visited...I want to say it's season 3 or earlier.

Comment: A good answer. But just to make sure, was Mitchell's introduction in _Avalon_ his first time through the stargate? Or was it just his first appearance on the show?

Comment: @Xantec: I just checked the opening (teaser) of Avalon and it shows him approach the stargate in deference. From his expression it is safe to assume it's the first time he even sees (let alone use) the gate himself, although he knew the SG-1 reports before.

Comment: Well, on episode 129 (of 213) Teal'c mentions that SG-1 has been to 133 planets. While some missions may have been to repeat planets, I couldn't seem them being on more than 160 individual missions through the stargate at that point. Assuming that ratio of missions to episodes remains consistent then by the end of the SG-1 show the team would have been on roughly 264 missions through the stargate.